# dlclose a library loaded with RTLD_NODELETE

Tags: c, dlopen

I can't understand the full sense of closing with dlclose a library opened with dlopen and the RTLD_NODELETE. If I correctly understand RTLD_NODELETE makes the library stay in memory until the end of program execution, so dlclosing it has no effect on memory occupancy. So is it really a bad practice not calling dlclose in this case? If so, why?
Thanks.

Comment: `RTLD_NODELETE` seems to be a (dirty) workaround for cases when library is being loaded/unloaded frequently to avoid extra overhead.

Comment: My use case is having multiple plugin libraries which define the same global variable (a factory instance). When I load one then the factory symbol is binded, but when it is unloaded the symbol remains binded so that the code in another plugin still refers to the factory symbol from the first library, and if the library has been unloaded then a segfault happens. That's why I'm loading with RTLD_NODELETE but at this point I wonder if there's still need to dlclose the plugin library at all.

Comment: It seems that you have an issues with plugin dependencies. Code from another plugin should not depend on some previously loaded plugin. Actually it even should not be aware of other plugins existence.

Comment: @VTT Also used to implement `STB_GNU_UNIQUE` symbols as explained  e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39123106/2170527).

Comment: @VTT Plugins actually do not know anything about each other. But each of them register its components in the same static global factory, so each plugin compiled separately creates a global factory symbol in its binary. If I understand correctly, at runtime the factory symbol in the first loaded plugin is binded and used also by the code in other plugins loaded later. Obviously if the second plugin is loaded and then the first one is unloaded then the factory will no longer be present for the code in the second plugin.

Comment: It would be a good idea to change it so plugins never register themselves, and let plugin manager that loads plugin library to register it after library is loaded and then unregister before it is unloaded. Plugins should be not aware of this plugin manager or any global factories existence.

Answer (score 0):

As for the original question, the answer is no - you don't need to call `dlclose` on `RTLD_NODELETE` library as it won't do anything.

On the other hand instead of keeping all your plugins loaded forever (wasting resources e.g. memory) you could link them all to a helper shared library that would hold shared state (i.e. global symbol you mentioned). This library would get loaded with the first plugin and unloaded with the last one.

Comment: The fact is thet I don't know which plugins the user would want to use. They are specified at runtime. And they are divided in sets so that different global symbols are defined for each set, so I can't even tell which global symbols will be needed since this is up to the user's choice at runtime.
Anyway, I'd be glad to have a reference to an example of the helper shared library technique you mention, since I might be wrong and it could be useful for me. Thanks.